# Find FileStreams that are not closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I want to know if there exist and tool in visual studio (or plugin) that can be used to locate FileStream variable that not are closed.

**Background**
I was assigned to write code to a existing application. The code I was working on worked fine then when I used it together with the existing code. I got

> IOException
>
> The process cannot access the file '[Filepath]' because
> it is being used by another process.

I have no idea were code is that cause this that is why I'm asking if a tool like this exist.

Comment: do you have access to the source for the older code?  Can you step through it to see where it might be keeping a file locked?

Comment: Yes but the source is pretty big so that's why I'm looking for a more automated tool.

Comment: What "big" mean? Just use debugger, filter only IOException and you can easily find it. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Analysis in Visual Studio Ultimate or Professinal includes a rule to detect that both local variables that are disposable (like `FileStream`) are disposed of before going out of scope (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) as well as a rule to make sure types that have disposable fields are also disposable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx)

Neither of which will really do anything detect whether another process has a file in use.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using JetBrains ReSharper. I honestly have fallen in love with the tool as it immediately allowed me to identify a number of issues with my code and fix them just as easily.

Give it a try, its free for 30 days: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ and see if it will help clean up some of the issues you've inherited.